# Требуется написать программу для удаления фона

Tags: c, php

В общем есть jpg картинка с белым фоном, ее нужно преобразовать в прозрачную. Язык особо не важен, но лучше на пхп или си, чтобы приложение было кроссплатформенным. Вопрос в следующем, какие библиотеки/языки лучше использовать? Пробовал opencv, но думаю, с ним нужно долго разбираться, а времени не очень много.
Такой вариант не предлагать, слишком много шума

```
<?php
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"])) {
        echo("success");
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/image-creator/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
        $im = ImageCreateFromPng($_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
        $col = imagecolorat($im,0,0);
        imagecolortransparent ($im, $col);
        imagecopyresampled ($im, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im), imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
        imagepng($im,"transparent-".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
        $preview = imagecreatetruecolor(88,87); 
        imagecopyresampled ($preview, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 87, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
        $col = imagecolorat($preview,0,0);
        imagecolorset($preview, $col, 255, 255, 255);
        imagepng($preview,"preview-".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
        imagedestroy($preview);   
        imagedestroy($im); 
    } else {
        echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
    }
?>
```

Comment: нужно заменить белый на прозрачный? обрубленные края, дырки в картинке (если на ней есть белый) вас волнуют?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Заранее пардон если не очень точно понял в чём у вас задача и в чём проблема.*

1) JPG сам по себе не поддерживает прозрачность. Поэтому Вам и нужен PNG например (хотя бы в качестве выходного формата) - а главное в поисковике вводить PNG вместо JPG. ;-)

2) Если надо кроссплатформенно, то я б рекомендовал Java, поскольку поддержка изображений разных форматов там непосредственно в API. Сниппетов кода в интернете много ([например, похожий вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665406/)) - если не поможет, напишите - найду в собственных закромах.

3) Одна из проблем JPG для вас будет в том, что белый фон не абсолютно белый (поэтому вы и видите "много шума", как я понял), Вам нужно определить некоторый "пороговый" уровень фона и проверять каждую точку - если она светлее, то маскируем её прозрачностью.

UPD: Нашел (своё)

```
protected void makeImagesTransparent(BufferedImage[] imgs) {

    for(int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(imgs[i].getWidth(), imgs[i].getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        bi.getGraphics().drawImage(imgs[i], 0, 0, null);
        DataBuffer ar = bi.getAlphaRaster().getDataBuffer();
        int transpColor = ar.getElem(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < ar.getSize(); j++) {
            int color = ar.getElem(j);
            // примерное условие проверки цвета точки с "порогом"
            if (((color >> 16) & 0xFF) + ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) + (color & 0xFF) > 700)
                ar.setElem(j, color & 0x00FFFFFF);
        } // for
        imgs[i] = bi;
    } // for
} // makeImageTransparent
```

4) А да, белый цвет в центре тоже будет заменён на прозрачный, если это нежелательно, то надо не просто по всем точкам идти, а алгоритм заливки использовать. Правда это уже не очень хорошо в пример вместится.

Comment: Что-то типа "взять точку 1,1 и рекурсивно по 8 окружающим искать совпадения", самое простое

Comment: спасибо, все заработало.